# How to run a command/process through Linux systemd after screen wake up?

Tags: linux, display, systemd, powersave

I have an old Linux problem without any solution so maybe you can help me please?!

Are there any possibilites to run a cli command/start a process through any `systemd` handled event after **screen wake-up**? **Not system wake-up from suspend**!!!, **just** after **screen wake-up** after screen blank as power saving function. There are endless redundant questions about the real system wake-up from standby on the net but sadly I have not found any for only power saving screen blank.

If this can not be reached by `systemd`, any other solution for it? Is it possible somehow or I have to simply forget such a thing?

Lot of thanks in advance for any type of help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While @mashuptwice 's answer seems also perfect, at the end I solved the 'problem' through the following thread: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28181/how-to-run-a-script-on-screen-lock-unlock

Based on the thread there is a possibility to trigger just on 'screen-blank' *(without real 'locked' state)*, but also on 'locked' status.

Comment: In order to qualify as an answer, ALL the information of the answer must be here and it should not be necessary to follow a link to learn the answer. Please fix this answer or it is likely it will be deleted.

Comment: Next time consider adding that you use gnome, that way you can get more detailed on-point answers. Also please add all of the information into your answer, as link-only answers are not acceptable.

Comment: Sorry for it. GNOME was originally indifference as I just asked for any generic solution. @mashuptwice your was perfect, but I thought will check the others and later stayed with them. There is no any type of critics on your help!

If the self-answer is not enough currently, I will expand it more detailet if I have some more minutes for it. I'm a bit ruoutinless here, but of course there is no goal for make any problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with `xscreensaver`.

From `xscreensaver` man:

> --watch   Prints a line each time the screensaver changes state: when the screen blanks, locks, unblanks, or when the running hack is
> changed. This option never returns; it is intended for use by shell
> scripts that want to react to the screensaver in some way. An example
> of its output would be:
>
> ```
> BLANK Fri Nov  5 01:57:22 1999
> RUN 34
> RUN 79
> RUN 16
> LOCK Fri Nov  5 01:57:22 1999
> RUN 76
> RUN 12
> UNBLANK Fri Nov  5 02:05:59 1999
> ```
>
> The above shows the screensaver activating, running three different
> hacks, then locking (perhaps because the lock-timeout went off) then
> unblanking (because the user became active, and typed the correct
> password.) The hack numbers are their index in the `programs' list
> (starting with 1, not 0, as for the --select command.)
>
> For example, suppose you want to run a program that turns down the
> volume on your machine when the screen blanks, and turns it back up
> when the screen un-blanks. You could do that by running a Perl program
> like the following in the background. The following program tracks the
> output of the --watch command and reacts accordingly:
>
> ```
> #!/usr/bin/perl
>
>
> my $blanked = 0;
> open (my $in, "xscreensaver-command -watch |") || die;
> while (<$in>) {
>   if (m/^(BLANK|LOCK)/) {
>     if (!$blanked) {
>       system ("sound-off");
>       $blanked = 1;
>     }
>   } elsif (m/^UNBLANK/) {
>     system ("sound-on");
>     $blanked = 0;
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> Note that LOCK might come either with or without a preceding BLANK
> (depending on whether the lock-timeout is non-zero), so the above
> program keeps track of both of them.

Comment: Sorry for the very late answer, I simply did not had more time for the 'problem' itself in the last some month, but at the end I handled the 'problem' with the help of the following thread: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28181/how-to-run-a-script-on-screen-lock-unlock